# Angular $compile outputted link-function gives me "undefined is not a function", why?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am trying to create an Angular directive which would divides a given collection of elements over a given number of columns.

[image: the idea]
The content of this directive i could like to use as the template for the individual items.

My testing area is: http://jsfiddle.net/e5aYt/1/

My problemen is: `$compile` returns a linking-function for a given template but when i want to apply this function with the local scope i get the error 'undefined is not a function' (twice, for every binding 1?).

[image: the compiling code]

All looks correct (i think, but the browser/angular disagrees with me), the `itemScope`-variable does indeed contain 1 element of my object-collection. And the itemTemplate does contain the template as intended.

What am i missing?

Comment: sure seems overcomplicated and an array element is not an angular scope

Comment: 'overcomplicated'? Why?
But seems i overlooked that object ≠ scope option :) thanks, a new point of investigation.

Comment: can do most of this with `ng-repeat` and some filters

Comment: I don't see how to do what i want with a simple repeater.
I have collections of `n` elements, i want to distribute them over a set of columns, 6 element result in only 1 column, 24 get 3 columns and 47 elements (and more) go in to 4 columns. There are multiple kinds of collections, each of different types of data and thus different types of displays. And besides, it's fun to make this kind of directive to see it work... eventually.  

`scope.$new(true)` is what saves the day, hours of googling :)
(will post a working solution soon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to charlietfl i got on the right track.

A working solution is shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/e5aYt/2/

Passing a plain javascript object as scope does not work, unfortunately angular does not give a very informative error message.
Using `scope.$new(true)` to create an object of the correct type and passing the content of one object to another with `angular.extend` solved the issue i had.

[image]

Results into (including the not visible data-age attribute):

[image]